# how to add roles on the login page?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I've using Spring and webflow to create a login page, but I do not know how to import the value of the database tables and put it in my program to control access with user roles. Here are some of my code.
the security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


        <security:http auto-config="true">
            <security:form-login login-page="/app/main" default-target-url="/app/account" />
            <security:logout logout-url="/app/logout" logout-success-url="/app/main" />
        </security:http>

        <security:authentication-manager>
            <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userServices">
                <security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>
            </security:authentication-provider>
        </security:authentication-manager>

        <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userServices" />
            <property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
            <constructor-arg>
                <ref  bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

and this is my account-flow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <secured attributes="ROLE_USER"/>

    <view-state id="home" view="accountHome.xhtml">
    </view-state>

</flow>
```

the methode where i loadAccesto my user

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserEntity user = userDao.loadUserByUserName(userName);

        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Etulisateur introuvable '%s'", userName)); 
        }

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        User userDetails = new User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassWord(), authorities);

        return userDetails;
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that your code works with a hardcoded "ROLE_USER", you now want to go onto the next step of reading a role from a database and populating it with that (i.e., you have a database access, not Spring question) -- or does your code not even work with ROLE_USER hardcoded, yours is a Spring question?

Comment: no said with hardcoded "ROLE_USER" they work greatly but i want to to the next step is to reading a role from database. for more detail user table contains a field role is not a relational table